# How to replace a string in a URL with each integers in a list using loops?

Tags: c#

I have a list that contains numbers, example from 1 to 30.

I am trying to write a loop which takes each of those numbers one at a time and puts them in a URL.

This is the code for adding everything to the list

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Month Number");
            var month = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Day Start");
            var daystart = Console.ReadLine();
            int ds = Int32.Parse(daystart);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Day End");
            var dayend = Console.ReadLine();
            int de = Int32.Parse(dayend);

            var dayList = Enumerable.Range(ds, de).ToList();
            dayList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This is the URL i want use to replace each day number.

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipc/availability/avaday?AdultCount=1&A_City=RIX&D_City=OSL&D_Month=2019" + month + "&D_Day=" + day + "&IncludeTransit=false&TripType=1&CurrencyCode=GBP");
```

I've no idea how would i go about it, sorry for the lack of loop codes.

EDIT: Okay, I've found a solution: I've converted the List to ArrayList and used them like so:

```
            ArrayList urlList = new ArrayList();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Month Number");
            var month = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Day Start");
            var daystart = Console.ReadLine();
            int ds = Int32.Parse(daystart);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Day End");
            var dayend = Console.ReadLine();
            int de = Int32.Parse(dayend);

            var dayList = Enumerable.Range(ds, de).ToList();
            dayList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            foreach (var days in dayList)
            {     
                urlList.Add("https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipc/availability/avaday?AdultCount=1&A_City=RIX&D_City=OSL&D_Month=2019" + month + "&D_Day=" + days + "&IncludeTransit=false&TripType=1&CurrencyCode=GBP");
            }

            foreach (string url in urlList)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            }
```

This works perfectly fine for me, hope this helps to some of you.

Comment: learn about query strings, and build accordingly...

Comment: FYI:  "Use of any automated system or software to extract data from this website for commercial purposes is prohibited."  From the [terms of use](https://www.norwegian.com/en-ca/booking/booking-information/legal/terms-of-use/) of the website you are trying to access.

Comment: I know, i'm not going to, this is just for practicing web crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

```
string url;
for (int i = daystart; i <= dayend; i++)
{
     url = "https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipc/availability/avaday?AdultCount=1&A_City=RIX&D_City=OSL&D_Month=2019" + month + "&D_Day=" + i + "&IncludeTransit=false&TripType=1&CurrencyCode=GBP";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I've found a different solution (see Edit)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I've found using ArrayList

```
            ArrayList urlList = new ArrayList();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Month Number");
            var month = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Day Start");
            var daystart = Console.ReadLine();
            int ds = Int32.Parse(daystart);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Day End");
            var dayend = Console.ReadLine();
            int de = Int32.Parse(dayend);

            var dayList = Enumerable.Range(ds, de).ToList();
            dayList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            foreach (var days in dayList)
            {     
                urlList.Add("https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipc/availability/avaday?AdultCount=1&A_City=RIX&D_City=OSL&D_Month=2019" + month + "&D_Day=" + days + "&IncludeTransit=false&TripType=1&CurrencyCode=GBP");
            }

            foreach (string url in urlList)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            }
```

Comment: Just about any solution that uses`ArrayList` is better off using `List<T>`,  in your case consider using `List<int>`